# Issue with StickyListHeaders and CursorAdapter, Is it possible to create sticky headers with created_at date

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a simple Activity where I use `LoaderManager` to fetch my database results in a cursor.
This works great but the problem is when I'm trying to use [StickyListHeader](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) to display the results grouped by their `created at` date.

The StickyListHeader API says

> Your adapter must implement `StickyListHeadersAdapter` interface to function with StickyListHeadersListView. `getHeaderId()` must return a unique integer for every section. A valid implementation for a list with alphabetical sections is the return the char value of the section that position is a part of.

1. Is it a good practice to check whether an object/row belongs to a single group(based on created_at) during rendering the list itself(in `newView/bindView`) ? Say, I have defined a method `isANewGroup` which returns true or false by comparing the created_at attribute of current and previous elements in the cursor.
2. Bit confused with how `StickyListHeader` works. Could anyone point me to a good direction which fits my case ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

Did the group check on `bindView` and used a sectionMap(a simple `SparseIntArray`) to keep track of these groups. And on `getHeaderID`, I returned the groupID corresponding to each item's position from my sectionMap.

Attaching a sample [gist](https://gist.github.com/vishrayne/fee4093c0dd0767efc85) of my custom sectioned adapter.

Comment: Terrible Answer. No help to the community whatsoever.

Comment: @surfer190 How can I help you improve this situation?

Comment: @BenjaminFell see [here](https://gist.github.com/vishrayne/fee4093c0dd0767efc85). Let me know if you need more details :)

Comment: @surfer190 Made a mistake! Thanks for pointing it out and cheers :)